# repeat the entire AHK code

Tags: autohotkey

```
XButton2:: 
if( not GetKeyState("t","P") )
    Send {t down}
    While GetKeyState("XButton2","P"){

       Sendinput, f
       sleep, 30
    }  

    return

XButton2 Up::Send {t up}
```

So what this code does is when I press and hold XButton2 it holds "t" down and while "t" is down it spams "f". What im trying to do is to repeat this action of holding "t" down and spaming "f" every 100ms, not sure what to do next